# Shuffle an array made in a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, shuffle

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cxo2y368/4/)

```
        var test = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        var Quiz = [];
        for (var i=0; i<5; i++){
            shuffle(test)
            Quiz[i] = {
                options: [],
                correct: Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1)
            };
                for(quizS of Quiz){
                quizS.options.push = test
            }

        }

        console.log(Quiz);


        function shuffle(arra1){
            var ctr = arra1.length, temp, index;
            while (ctr > 0) {
                index = Math.floor(Math.random() * ctr);

                ctr--;

                temp = arra1[ctr];
                arra1[ctr] = arra1[index];
                arra1[index] = temp;
            }
            return arra1;
        }
```

So I am trying to create an array (Quiz) through a for loop where each individual array has its own randomized order from a certain array (test).
What I'm getting in the console log is the same randomized order across all arrays. How do I randomize/shuffle it for each separate array?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your required solution:

**You have to clone the array inorder to assign it without changing  the original array**

use, `slice(0)` to clone array.

**`var a = shuffle(test).slice(0)`**

```js
var test = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

var Quiz = [];
var random = {};

function shuffle(arra1) {
    var ctr = arra1.length, temp, index;
    while (0 !== ctr) {
        index = Math.floor(Math.random() * ctr);
        ctr -= 1
        temp = arra1[ctr];
        arra1[ctr] = arra1[index];
        arra1[index] = temp;
    }
    return arra1;
}

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var a = shuffle(test).slice(0)
    Quiz.push({
        options: a,
        riktig: Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1)
    });
}


console.log(Quiz);
```

**Please run the above snippet**

[**Here is a DEMO plunker for the same**](https://plnkr.co/edit/vWQVo95ednev2vAkVIOS?p=preview)

Comment: @Alan, have you checked the answer? Any help more needed?